# dynamic xml layout rotation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two buttons on my main activity and when pressed I want to call the exact same activity exept that on one the layout is rotated 180 degrees. Is there any way to do this (like rotate based on an extra passed from main activity) do I really need to create two different activities with practically the same code in their respective java file?

EDIT: when I say exact same activity I don't mean the same as main. It's just the same for those two buttons...

Comment: Did you play around with `setRequestedOrientation(int requestedOrientation)` in your `Activity`? I'm not sure whether the rotation should apply to the current orientation (i.e. do you support both landscape & portrait, or is your activity fixed in a particular orientation?), so you may need to add some statements to pick the appropriate 'inverse'. Let's assume you're targeting API level 9+ *and* your app is fixed into portrait, then, for example, try `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT`). Note: this *will* destroy and recreate your activity.

Comment: @MH I feel like this is the right answer but it doesn't seem to do anything till now. I'll play around with it a little more, thanks. I'm calling setRequestedOrientation in my onCreate btw, is it possible that this creates an infinite loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a solution for you. Use a custom reverse view as a wraper to reverse the whole layout.

Try to run the sample code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int layoutId = R.layout.main;
        View content = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutId, null);

        ReverseView wraper = new ReverseView(this);
        wraper.addView(content);
        setContentView(wraper);
    }

    public class ReverseView extends FrameLayout {

        public ReverseView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            int px = getWidth() / 2;
            int py = getHeight() / 2;
            canvas.rotate(180, px, py);
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this works fine for the button but how do I add the whole xml layout in there? Do I have to do it for each element sepperately?

Comment: @Billakosama Hi, i edit the code to show how to add the whole layout.

Comment: While this worked for me and I thank you, it should be noted that this implementation only inverts the image and not the actual place of the buttons etc. If for example a button was on the upper side, now its shown on the lower side but you still have to tap on the upper side to click it...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the orientation in your activity by adding the following code.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

And you can also create a new layout xml in layout-land/, and when your activity enter the landscape mode, it will try to load the different layout.

Comment: I'm not trying to get into landscape mode, I want a full reverse. Still this may be the function I need, as MH commented...